# opening and viewing 32 bit tiff image sequence in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, video, stack, bit, tiff

I have a singe image.tiff file, a video sequence exported as 32 bit tiff. I would like to open it as an image stack in MATLAB, and be able to navigate frame by frame. I believe `implay()` is the way to do this in `matlab`. If I try this I get `"Error occurred while attempting to read file: image.tiff  Details of error: Incorrect chunk size information in AVI file."` Does `implay()` only work with the `.avi` format? do I need to covert this 32 tiff to a  `.avi` before i can use `implay()`? or is there maybe some other (`non-implay()`) way of opening this as a stack?

Thanks

Comment: what about using `imshow` inside a `for` loop with `pause`?

Comment: yea just tried that and it worked perfectly, except that I would like to be able to move backwards in the stack as well

Comment: What about using a pause to get a key from keyboard to choose if you go to the next or previous frame.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create an image stack and use *implay* to view it. The function accepts multiple types of arguments, for grayscale images it should be provided with an array of size N x M x K where K is the number of frames, (N,M) is the image size. For color images an array of size NxMx3xK is expected.

To create the array for the case with multiple files, each containing a frame you have multiple options, the simplest is probably to use the *cat* function for concatenation:

```
image_stack = [];
for i = 1: num_frames
     curr_image = imread(sprintf('frame_%04d_color.tif', i));
     image_stack = cat(4, image_stack, curr_image);
end

implay(image_stack);
```

This solution is a bit slower, than if the *image_stack* is allocated beforehand though.

For your case with a single TIFF file, the frames need to be extracted in a manner suitable for the storage format, but this is a separate problem from the video replay.